# Android cassandra client example

Tags: android, cassandra

I need to update an Android app to talk to a Cassandra database. Can anybody point me to an example or libraries to support this?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you will not do this directly.  You should develop an appropriate API (probably a web service, RESTful or otherwise) or mobile web site.  Then, your web service/site will sit between the Android app and Cassandra.  You can use the server-side language and framework of your choice.

**EDIT**: A good approach to try is a RESTFUL API with [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS).

Comment: I'm a database newbe. Are there any resources or examples that can help shine the way?

Comment: Have you chosen a server-side language yet?