# Cassandra DB For Android, Its APIs and How to use it?

Tags: android, nosql, cassandra

I have been searching for NoSQL databases. In my research on the Internet I have found that Cassandra DB is the most widely used NoSQL DB. I also want to use it in my Android App but did not find anything about its Android Version.

Is there an API like CouchDB has Ektorp for using it in Android? 
Am I going in the right direction with the decision of Cassandra DB?

I need its Android API and tutorial to start with? I only found this link on StackOverflow but it did not help me.

[Android cassandra client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745802/android-cassandra-client-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical approach is to use a web server to interface into cassandra whereby you send requests to server and it gives you an XML/JSON response, that is what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745802/android-cassandra-client-example) means by creating a RESTful service.

One of the applications that made it to datastax's next great developer competition finals was an android app that did exactly this, here is the [project's code](https://github.com/shehaaz/AndroidCassandra).

Comment: Use Virgil and Loopj. Here is a blog post on how to RESTfully connect to Cassandra with an Android app: http://www.shehaaz.com/2013/05/blog-2-cassandra-resting-with-virgil.html

Comment: Hi Lyuben. thanks!! I just need to know one more thing before accepting it as my final implementation part.

Will it be so flexible and easy to use like CouchDB or it has some complexities?

Comment: Thank you Shehaaz, it would help me.

Comment: @PJakhar That is an opinion based question which I can't answer objectively because I don't have much experience with CouchDB. Having done something similar recently, I'd say that adding the intermittent step of a webserver as an interface to cassandra complicates things, but querying C* is highly flexible if you get your data model right!

Comment: @Lyuben I am simplifying my question. I want to use Cassandra as local database on my Android phone for my application. In parallel I want to push all the data to the server. Will it serve this purpose better than other NoSQL databases. Because in this way I will be able to use same data on both sides - on my website and on my android phone.

Comment: @PJakhar "I want to use Cassandra as local database on my Android phone for my application": I would use the built in MySQLite DB. You should setup Cassandra on a remote server...Use Apache Tomcat to talk to your java code. What makes Cassandra stand out from the crowd is the Cassandra Query Language...You are basically writing SQL-like commands to a NoSQL Database...in CouchDB you have to query the DB using Javascript...

Comment: Okay, Thanks Shehaaz.

I know that in CouchDB I can use it both; as a database on Android side and on the Server side, there is no need of managing two databases. Can not I do same with Cassandra?